What is the mechanism by which placing a spoon in a cup of water being heated in a microwave oven prevents the water from becoming super-heated?
Should I place a spoon in a cup of liquid before heating it in a mircowave? explains why one should do this and the safe ways of doing it, but it doesn't provide the physics behind it.
What is the mechanism by which placing a spoon in a cup of water being heated in a microwave oven prevents the water from becoming super-heated?

The accepted answer there points it out: it doesn’t prevent the water from boiling, but provides nucleation sites so that it boils off slowly rather than all at once when it is afterward disturbed.

@controlgroup. It took me a while to find it. "nucleation" isn't mentioned in the accepted answer, or any other. It's mentioned only in a comment on the question post.

Normally, placing metallic objects in microwave is not a good idea.

See also boiling chip.

@Chemomechanics, some spoons have very smooth and rounded surfaces with no obvious nucleation points. Does the fact that they are metal make the difference?

I don't know whether microwave-induced charging, for example, plays any important role. Even a superficially smooth metal utensil can be expected to exhibit microscale surface roughness. Even the crevice between two smooth objects in contact can serve as a nucleation point. Possibly a metal spoon is simply the handiest thing present when one's preparing a hot liquid.
